# Evaluating Limits - big fraction

Tags: limits

is anyone able to help me evaluate this limit :). What I have done so far is expand out the fraction by multiplying the top and bottom of the fraction by the conjugate of the numerator. But, this produced a very large fraction which doesn't seem like it would help. Thankyou

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n^2-6n+8}-(n+6)$$

Comment: You should not just alternate the whole question like this. This behavior would make the answer before your edit become moot.

Comment: I realised I posted the wrong question. Sorry @xbh

Answer (score 1):

For the new question, complete the square under the radical and you have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{(n-3)^2-1}-n-6$$  The intuitive approach is that the $-1$ won't matter as $n$ gets large, so ignore it and you have $-9$

The more formal one is to write 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{(n-3)^2-1}-n-6=\lim_{n \to \infty}(n-3)\sqrt{1-\frac 1{(n-3)^2}}-n-6$$ 
and note the square root goes to $1-\frac 1{2(n-3)^2}$ with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{n^2-6n+8}-(n+6)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^2-6n+8-(n+6)^2}{\sqrt{n^2-6n+8}+(n+6)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-18n-28}{\sqrt{n^2-6n+8}+(n+6)}=-9\text{ , dividing by $n$ }$

Answer (score 0):

Divide both the denominator and the numerator by $n^4$, then apply the law of arithmetic operations of limits.

Rigorously speaking, when compute the limit of square roots, if you have not learnt anything about *continuous function*, then you need to prove them separately. E.G. you need to additionally prove something like 
$$
\lim_n \sqrt {1 + \frac 1n} = 1
$$
by $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

UPDATE:

For this limit, you can divide the top and the bottom by $n$ after you do the conjugate part, and the rest are the same as above.

Answer (score 0):

All that matters is the
$4n^3$ in the numerator
and the
$2n^4$ in the denominator.
All the other terms
are small compared to these.

So the fraction behaves
for large $n$ like
$\dfrac{4n^3}{2n^4}
=\dfrac{2}{n}
$
which goes to zero.